# 'when' expression must be exhaustive error when using adapters

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to do something like this:

```
class MyPagerAdapter : PagerAdapter() {
    override fun getItem(position: Int) = when(position) {
        0 -> Fragment0()
        1 -> Fragment1()
    }

    override fun getCount() = 2
}
```

I am sure that the adapter contains only 2 items, so `getCount()` simply returns 2. But it shows an error message said that `'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'else' branch`. I understand that I can add an `else` to solve it, but it's really ugly to write code like:

```
    when(position) {
        0 -> Fragment0()
        1 -> Fragment1()
        else -> Fragment()    // Impossible to get here
    }
```

Is there any better way to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Addition to all answers, a specificity of Kotlin is that some keywords return values. This is the case of if/else and when. The compiler must have an option to return something when we want to get a value out of a non-exhaustive when.

Comment: You can also check for RecyclerView.NO_POSITION (the constant evaluates to -1 I believe) and throw an exception or do nothing.

Comment: Well, if you are sure that 0 and 1 are the only possible value you can `else` on `1`:  `else -> Fragment1()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) If it impossible to get at else branch than you can

> throw IllegalStateException("Fragment $position is not correct")

Your code can be changed at any time. And it will help you to better understand that you send not correct values.

2) Also if you have only two cases than you can use if (..) {} else {} statement

3) You can use Enum values to do not have else branch (instead of position).

Comment: 4) You could use a [Sealed Class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) (which is sort of an enum)  - but actually neither enum nor sealed classes work here because the overriden function gives you an `Int` and it can't be changed because it's part of the framework.

Comment: you could create a local extension function on Int to convert it to the sealed class or enum. But you will end up with the same problem just move it to this new funtion. depending on the needs of the project this could be a "good enough" solution

Answer (score 5):

There's no way for compiler to figure out that `position` is `in 0 until 1`.
You must add `else` branch and hope it won't ever be called:

```
else -> throw AssertionError()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it the proper way, throw an exception in the else branch. Keep in mind that may be in the future someone else will be maintaining your code base and will try to use this adapter in another situation.

I know this seems unlikely right now and unnecessary extra effort, but getting used to these small things is important IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said if you are sure there won't be more elements you can change the else branch to `throw IllegalStateException("Fragment $position is not correct")`. Trying to use and enum or sealed class to make the when case exaustive will just move this problem to the function you use to tranform the Int to the new restricted type.

Another option if you are completly sure there won't be any more options and want to maintain a concise declaration is to use an if expression:

```
fun getItem(position: Int) = if(position == 0) Fragment0() else Fragment1()
```

The problem with this approach is that is not extensible if you end up having new elements on the adapter. Also if an invalid position is passed, instead of crashing it will return a Fragment1() instance.
Depending on your needs could be a good option or not.

Answer (score 2):

This might or might not be a proper alternative, but could let the `position` accept any value whatsoever, and adjust the values with modulo. In that case you need `else` only to catch case of actually missing entries:

```
class MyPagerAdapter : PagerAdapter() {
    override fun getItem(position: Int) = when(position % getCount()) {
        0 -> Fragment0()
        1 -> Fragment1()
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("Someone forgot to add enough fragment cases to 'when' clause!")
    }

    override fun getCount() = 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you got that error in function that is not return anything, you can add below row to end of the when condition;

```
else -> {}
```